# React Native/TypeScript - How to manage state in functional component and apply flexible style with FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Can anyone tell me how to solve these things?
1.if the list is pressed, I'd like to change the background color of the list
beige(#FFF5E7)  to white(#FBFBFB)

2.Also, I'd like to change the read value of the Object fales to true with useState

Problem is that if I pressed the list, whole background color of the list will be changed.

index.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { DETAIL } from '../../sample';
import { Object } from './sample';

export default function sample() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(Object);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  let Element;

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const readState = () => {
      navigation.navigate(NOTICE_DETAIL);
      const readValue = [...state];
      let value = { ...readValue[0] };
      value.read = true;
      readValue[0] = value;
      setState(readValue);
    };
    if (state[0].read) {
      Element = (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={readState}>
          <View style={[styles.row, { backgroundColor: '#FBFBFB' }]}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <View style={styles.end}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{item.text}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.time}>{item.time}</Text>
              </View>
              <Text style={styles.content}>{item.content}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    } else {
      Element = (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={readState}>
          <View style={[styles.row, { backgroundColor: '#FFF5E7' }]}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <View style={styles.end}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{item.text}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.time}>{item.time}</Text>
              </View>
              <Text style={styles.content}>{item.content}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
    return Element;
  };
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        extraData={Object}
        data={Object}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
    </View>
  );

}
```

Object.ts

```
export const Object = [
 {
  id: 1,
  text: 'testtesttest',
  content: 'testtesttest'
  read: false
},
{ 
  id: 2,
  text: 'testtesttest',
  content: 'testtesttest'
  read: false
}
  id: 3,
  text: 'testtesttest',
  content: 'testtesttest'
  read: false
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add inline styles into the component style props along with static styles,

For Example:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={readState}>
    <View style={[styles.row, { backgroundColor: item.read ? '#FBFBFB' : 'FFF5E7' }]}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.end}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item.text}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.time}>{item.time}</Text>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.content}>{item.content}</Text>
       </View>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I need to manage the state in functional component and I also want to change the read value false to true. thank you for your answer anyway

Comment: ok then, you have to useState and manage the state on some user actions and update the state values to dynamic handle backgroundColor the same code also helps you but you only have to manage the state.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your `readState` function and `if (state[0].read) {`. You always change item with index 0 and then check `state[0].read` for all elements of your array.